# Why do many equations need squared powers?

Tags: soft-question, mathematics

It seems that an equation factor must be “squared” as a convenient approximation to balance out some other series of factors invisibly . Might $E=mc^{1.95}$  work as well as $E=mc^2$? Might $A^2+B^2=C^2$ also work if all the factors used the same but different power and be even more accurate? Does anyone know of such a triangle that the current formula comes out to an even number.